# Prevent the tooltip from disappearing in chart.js line graph

Tags: typescript, vue.js, chart.js, chart.jsv3

Is it possible to prevent the tooltip from disappearing when clicking outside the line graph itself? I want it to always be visible on the latest datapoint clicked.

Im using chart.js 3.9.1 in vue

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

Namespace: `options.plugins.tooltip`, the global options for the chart tooltips is defined in `Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip`.

for complete details, you can check [this link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html), my friend.

Comment: I've gone through the documentation but couldn't find an option to always have a tooltip visible as long as it is enabled